# Display only the Date not Date+Time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, plot

I would like to plot a bar plot. It shows the money for one day. The plot looks fine, but it displays one day like this "%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s". It would be nice, when it shows only "%y-%m-%d".

My dataframe looks like this:

```
            Erdtemp  Heizung   Money_H
DatumZeit                             
2021-04-28   4047.5       73  0.003613
2021-04-29  27469.4      504  0.024948
2021-04-30  27450.6      488  0.024156
2021-05-01  28186.3      420  0.020790
2021-05-02   9006.1       71  0.003515
```

I use this line to plot it:

```
Tab2_count.plot(kind='bar', y='Money_H', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Euro')
```

And the plot looks like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way to get rid of the 00:00:00 ?

Comment: little addition to the linked question; after assigning the plot to a variable `ax`, you can set the labels e.g. like `ax.set_xticklabels(Tab2_count.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_series())` in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your way works also flawlessly. `ax = Tab2_count.plot(kind='bar', y='Money_H', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Euro')

ax.set_xticklabels(Tab2_count.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_series())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DatetimeIndex.date()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) to get date part from `DatetimeIndex` object. Then use it before plot or after plot.

```py
df.index = df.index.date

df.plot(kind='bar', y='Money_H', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Euro')
```

Or

```py
axes = df.plot(kind='bar', y='Money_H', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Euro')

axes.set_xticklabels(df.index.date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried the first way, it works flawlessly :)